# Scrape the ajax pages using Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been trying to scrape stockx.com, which uses ajax to load data. If I use Python requests. I am able to get the source code of half the page and the rest of the page is not loaded. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
    
import time

request = requests.Session()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
    }

cookies = {
    'stockx_homepage': "sneakers",
    }

mainURL = "https://stockx.com/adidas-crazy-byw-x-2-ubiq"
print("timedelay...")
time.sleep(10)

#request for the link that I want to scrape
soupmain = BeautifulSoup(request.get(mainURL,headers=headers, cookies=cookies).content,"lxml")
pprint.pprint(soupmain.body)

print(soupmain.body)
```

I tried using selenium to interact with the page but stockx.com blocked me, Is there any other way other than selenium. Using only requests to get the whole source code of the page.

[This is image of the retrived html. the code is working fine but I want the rest of the page to load and then scrape it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d85j.png)

Comment: if it uses `AJAX` to load data then you can try to use `DevTools` (tab `Network`, filter `XHR` in `Chrome/Firefox` to find `URL` used by `AJAX`/`XHR` and then you can use this `URL` with `requests` - usually `AJAX` sends data as `JSON` and it doesn't need `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: better describe in question which data do you want to get from HTML. AJAX may send data in separated requests and it is important which request  get and which skip.

Comment: I tried copying the requests with the headers from devtools but it uses an API with an encrypted payload. So I am not able to retrieve the page source. 

2nd comment: I want the page course from the main product page. The image is also attached in the  question.

Comment: as you see page uses some methods to stop scripts/bots/spamers/hackers and it would need a lot of work and big knowledge (about encrypting and programming JavaScript) to recreate this all in Python. So you would have to recreate web browser in your code. And Selenium can be simpler method. You could search questions which describe how to modify code in Selenium to make it invisible for pages - but it needs to recompile C/C++ code. You may also try to use Qt framework and widget `WebKit` to create own web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks alot It seems difficult to modify the source code of selenium . I will look into that . Also the browser idea is . Thanks again